# When should I use engine.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);

Tags: android, andengine

I am looking at many of the andengine examples, and I am trying to understand when I need to use "getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true)". I understand that this might be helpful when a touch event triggers the removal of a sprite or entity. But why is is there in "PhysicsExample"

```java
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Touch the screen to add objects.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    final EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    engineOptions.getTouchOptions().setRunOnUpdateThread(true);
    return new Engine(engineOptions);
}
```

Do I need to make sure I only add bodies un the update thread because of Box2D? What iw ould like is to have a good understanding of that engine feature, and when to use it, and when I should not.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know , this line means that the touch inputs will only be processed on the update thread , so if you do anything when touching .. it'll be on update thread
in general , if you are using something that could be used by another thread at the same time , run it on updateThread [drawing sprites is done on a parallel thread , that's why you need to remove entities on the update thread]

the same applies to modifying lists

Comment: Jimmar -  could yu shed more light on how I would KNOW to use it or not? Right now my method of finding out is runtime errors. Which is far from ideal.